# Convert GWT-HighChart to image

Tags: java, image, gwt, highcharts, smartgwt

i use [GWT-HighCharts](http://www.moxiegroup.com/) in my SmartGWT project, en i need to convert the chart to image to show it on a TabSet. 
How can i do it ?

Comment: Please add more details. **Did you try anything at all?**

Comment: i create the chart in a Window and it work, then i need to transfer it in a TabSet, but when i add the layout contains the chart, it wasn't show. i said convert it to image, it will work, No?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [GWT Highcharts User Guide](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/userguide.jsp).

Exporting is disabled by default. You need to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

to enable exporting to PNG, JPEG, PDF, or SVG image.  Adding the above JS import enables exporting.